# PDFBox: How to print a range of pages from a PDF

Tags: java, netbeans, pdfbox

I sincerely don't know how to approach this. I'm new to this library (PDFBox) and i managed to implemented code (using Java), that prints any selected PDF.

Now i need to allow users specify a range of pages to print, if needed.
Here is the part of my code that handles printing...

```
          try
          {
                    // TODO add your handling code here:
                    PrintService myPrintService = findPrintService(printerCmb.getSelectedItem().toString());
                    PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
                   job.setPageable(doc);

                    job.setPrintService(myPrintService);
                    job.print( );
          }
          catch (PrinterException ex)
          {             
                    Logger.getLogger(PrintDialog.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);  

          }
```

What do i do next?

This is how i created "doc".

```
    public Pageable doc;  JFileChooser getPDF = new JFileChooser();
          FileFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("PDF File", "pdf");
          getPDF.setFileFilter(filter);
          getPDF.setDialogTitle("Select a PDF file");
          getPDF.showOpenDialog(getPDF);
          try
          {
                    Connection conn = null;
                    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(urlDist);
                    //SQLiteConnection new2 = new SQLiteConnection(urlDist, filename);
                    File selPdf = getPDF.getSelectedFile();
                    doc = PDDocument.load(selPdf);

                    if (doc != null)
                    {
                              count = doc.getNumberOfPages();
                              noPagestxt.setText(String.valueOf(count ));
                              filename = selPdf.getName();
                              fileNametxt.setText(filename);
                              pagesPrint.setEnabled(true);
                    }
                    // cleaning memory

                    // cleaning memory
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
                    Logger.getLogger(BioProject.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
          }
```

Comment: Where does "doc" come from?

Comment: `public Pageable doc;` and `doc = PDDocument.load(selPdf);` would not work. Anyway, in the meantime I found something that might work, the class `PageRanges`. That is a print job attribute, so use `PrintRequestAttributeSet attr = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
        attr.add(new PageRanges(1, 1));  job.print(attr);`

Comment: @TilmanHausherr, i'll try that now.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr, I've tried your solution, but i keep getting an error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Null range specified` even though i print out the integer variables and they aren't null; although if i input raw numbers like 1 and 5, the function work smoothly.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in it and have a look what is really in your variables. In Netbeans you can set a breakpoint by clicking on the line number on the left of your code. If there is nothing weird, then step into to see what really happens...

Comment: Thanks @TilmanHausherr, it's done. You could post an answer, so that i can accept it.

Comment: "done" means what - you solved the problem? Or that you did set the breakpoint and traced but it is still mysterious?

Comment: Solved the problem.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Please answer the question yourself, you have the actual code that works. It would be useful for other users, when I searched myself I couldn't find anything on SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I fixed the issue using user **TilmanHausherr**'s suggestion.
I specified the range using the `PageRanges()` function Here is the code.

```
...
 job.setPageable(doc);
 job.setPrintService(myPrintService);
 PrintRequestAttributeSet attr = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet(); 
 PageRanges pageRng = new PageRanges( lower , upper);
 attr.add(pageRng); 
 job.print(attr);
```

**NOTE:** `upper` and `lower` are Integer variables gotten from the user.

Answer (score -1):

```
Below is the code which can be helpful for  printing data from specific pages in the whole PDF file  hope this would solve your issue.

    PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load("Your PDF path");
    PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
    stripper.setStartPage( 1 );
    stripper.setEndPage( Integer.MAX_VALUE );
    List<String>  ans= Arrays.asList(changeText.split(",\n"));
    System.out.println(ans);
```

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer then mark as answered

Comment: Your code doesn't print anything to the printer. It just extracts text and outputs it.

Comment: But not to a paper printer. println is for stdout.